# Uso da palavra "metodologia"

Tags: definição

Em trabalhos de conclusão de curso e nomes de disciplinas (por exemplo, "*Metodologia de Desenvolvimento de Software Orientado a Objetos*"), é comum se observar o uso da palavra "metodologia" para descrever um método específico e não o estudo de métodos (como a palavra parece realmente designar segundo seu sufixo `logia` e sua definição [no dicionário Houaiss](http://houaiss.uol.com.br/busca?palavra=metodologia)):

> **metodologia**
>
> *substantivo feminino (1858)*
>
> 1. lóg ramo da lógica que se ocupa dos
>    métodos das diferentes ciências
>
> 1.1. parte de uma ciência que estuda os métodos aos quais ela própria recorre
>
> 1.2. lit em literatura, investigação e estudo, segundo métodos específicos, dos componentes e do caráter subjetivo de uma narrativa,
> de um poema ou de um texto dramático
>
> 2. p.ext. corpo de regras e
>    diligências estabelecidas para realizar uma pesquisa; método

Esse uso, para descrever um método específico e não o estudo geral de métodos (como no exemplo do nome da disciplina), é correto ou aceito?

Comment: Segundo a segunda definição que apresenta, sim.

Comment: @someonewithpc Mas a definição parece justamente indicar que o uso mais popular está equivocado. Não? Eu fiz uma edição na pergunta pra deixar mais claro.

Comment: Em Portugal, na Universidade do Minho usa-se **paradigma**, "Paradigma de programação por objetos"

Answer (score 1):

Não, não é correto. Já fiz um curso de metodologia científica em ciência da computação, no qual isso foi discutido.

Metodologia Científica é quando se propõe a se estudar diferentes métodos de pesquisa científica em uma determinada área.

Em geral, as pessoas escolhem um método científico e o utilizam, sem o discutir e comparar com outras abordagens. Nesse caso, o uso do termo metodologia científica estaria errado sim. Claro, do ponto de vista acadêmico.